# Definitely typed with angular material error on $mdSidenav

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material

Just trying to figure out why i am getting an error when toggling the `$mdSidenav` . This is not a breaking error as the code runs as it should , but i feel that i might be implementing it incorrectly in typescript.

I have added definitely typed and angular material with a simple controller like so

```
module app.layout {
interface IMenuModel {
    menuItems: app.layout.IMenuItems[];
    toggleSidenav(menuId: string): void; 
}

class MenuCtrl implements IMenuModel {

    menuItems: app.layout.IMenuItems[];

    constructor(private $mdSidenav: ng.material.ISidenavObject) {
        var vm = this;
    }

    toggleSidenav(menuId: string): void {
        this.$mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
        console.log(menuId);
    }
  }

  angular.module("app").controller("menuCtrl", MenuCtrl);
}
```

The heart of the code is compiled down to

```
     MenuCtrl.prototype.toggleSidenav = function (menuId) {
          this.$mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
          console.log(menuId);
     };
```

And the html is

```
<md-button ng-click="vm.toggleSidenav('left')" hide-gt-sm class="md-icon-button"> 
  menu  
</md-button>
```

So this works in the browser , the menu does toggle. However there is an error in the IDE stating that

[image]

I feel like i am not implementing this the "typescript" way if you will. the definitely typed `ng.material.ISidenavObject` looks like this

```
 interface ISidenavObject {
    toggle(): angular.IPromise<void>;
    open(): angular.IPromise<void>;
    close(): angular.IPromise<void>;
    isOpen(): boolean;
    isLockedOpen(): boolean;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change

```
constructor(private $mdSidenav: ng.material.ISidenavObject) {
```

to

```
constructor(private $mdSidenav: ng.material.ISidenavService) {
```

You can see corresponding [definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-material/angular-material.d.ts#L113).

Comment: and it works ... Of course because it returns the `ISidenavObject`. cheers